# angular js: programmatically instantiate a scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Simple case: Ask a controller `$scope` to create a child scope. This new scope would be applied to a `$compile`'s linking function -- i.e. programmatic directive instantiation.

My need falls just outside the `scope: true` declaration in the directive definition -- I **do** need a private directive scope but I **don't** want one created by the framework every time I instantiate the directive. Rather, I'd like to *reapply* the existing scope to a fresh linkage -- a fresh directive.

IOW, I want to teach a new dog old tricks.

I'm talking about the [scope obtained from the compiled directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) (see: **Retrieving Scopes from the DOM**).

Consider the scenario where the HTML representation of the directive (let's call it "half") may move in and out of and around the document. I merely want to save its state (let's call it "the other half") off and *reapply* it to a fresh half-compiled directive instance.

Scope hierarchy would be respected, i.e. this new directive instance would nestle itself in the same Angular-DOM area as it did in a former life so I *don't think* any worm holes would be opened nor anti-matter created.

A super-contrived [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/66QlSjeAe85GMc2VNPvZ) for your viewing pleasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want create private scope inside directive you can use [scope.$new](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24new) method like that:

```
app.directive('colorblock', function ($rootScope) {

    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
         var privateScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    }
   ...
});
```

It will create isolate scope.

Comment: For the plunk, better the scope is created outside the directive. (Plunk updated highlighting the use-case, for anyone that cares.) Still, this answers the question. Who* says angular doc is bad? * I do.

Comment: So in theory, can you compile a new directive (which has some functions on it's scope) by another directive using something like $compile('<test></test>')($rootScope.$new(true); ?